# How old do you have to be to partake in Stack Overflow Jobs?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I assume that you have to be an adult to partake in Stack Overflow Jobs, therefore making me ineligible, but I couldn't find anywhere that actually stated how old you need to be and I was wondering whether teenagers were actually allowed to get involved in Stack Overflow Jobs? Of course I lack the expertise, but I just wanted to ask the question, as it doesn't seem to state the required age anywhere.

Comment: I don't think Jobs is forcing you into child labor so I guess there is no age limit. Lower or upper bound for that matter.

Comment: I'd assume it would just depend on each individual company's hiring policies, local laws, etc.

Comment: I would think the lower limit would be 13 because that's the minimum age in the Terms of Service for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BSMP 16 in European Union. Which I have now left.

Comment: Are you looking to post jobs or apply for jobs? Also I don't think there any specific restriction for either (short of already mentioned 13/16 age limit in [CoC-age](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age))... Indeed companies can add any (legal) restrictions and "legal to work in xxxxx" is a common one.

Comment: @Zera if you mean brexit by that it's still 16 until the end of the transition period and even then it may remain 16 as a result of DPA 2018 (or even if SE just decide that's the case)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your interest! We strongly encourage students to look at the jobs on our site and learn more about requirements to help with their career planning. In regards to applying to jobs, that is dictated by local laws and individual company policies.

I don't want to discourage your excitement, but in the interest of your time, I would advise researching the companies before applying. Most roles require experience and many employers are looking to hire individuals with experience coding in professional settings.

-Ben
Product Marketing Manager, Stack Overflow Jobs